# Find all possible values of $(a+c)(b+c)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

The numbers $a,b,c$ satisfy the equalities

$$
\begin{align}(a+b)(b+c)&=c-a-1\\
(a+b)(a+c)&=b-c-1
\end{align}
$$

Find all possible values of the expression $(a+c)(b+c)$.

---

I tried adding, subtracting and multiplying equalities between each other and got: $$b^2-a^2=2c-a-b$$ $$(a+b)^2=b-a-2-2ac-2bc$$ but I can't get at least some values. Thanks a lot in advance, I'm really looking forward to a hint!

Comment: Please edit your question and use MathJax (like TeX) to write the mathematical symbols. It will be much clearer and generate much better responses.  I edited the first sentence to get you started.

Comment: Are $a,b,c$ integers ? because in the general case, I suppose that $2$ equations with $3$ variables would lead to a free range.

Comment: a,b,c  not necessary integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let

$$\begin{align}a+b&=m\\ b+c&=n\\
a+c&=k\end{align}$$

Then, the system of equation becomes :

$$
\begin{cases}mn=n-m-1\\
mk=m-k-1\end{cases}
$$

We quickly observe that, $m≠-1$ and $n≠0$ . Therefore, $\small{\thinspace k=\dfrac {m-1}{m+1}}$ .

Then, we can find the $nk$ :

$$
\small{\begin{align}nk=\frac{mn-n}{m+1}=-\frac {m+1}{m+1}=-1\thinspace . \end{align}}
$$

Comment: I can not figure out the reason for the *downvote* . Please, leave feedback in the comments for the something wrong answer. Otherwise, it is not possible to improve the answer to solve the reason for the downvote .

Comment: Yes, its correct! Thank you

Comment: @Starnex You are welcome . Please, if you can not follow the above solution, tell me and I can expand the answer, as much as I can .